# Workflow is not getting assigned for items

Tags: powershell-extensions, workflow

I'm creating a template and assigning a workflow to that template. But the items which are created from that template are not having the workflow value.

```
$template = New-Item  -Path "/sitecore/templates/Sensoft" -Name $importData.TemplateName -type "{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}"
$template."__Icon" = $importData.TemplateIcon
$sectionValue = New-Item -Parent $template -Name $importData.SectionName -type "{E269FBB5-3750-427A-9149-7AA950B49301}"
$standardvalues = New-Item -Parent $template -Name "__Standard Values" -type $template.ID
$standardvalues.'__Default workflow' = $importData.WorkFlowID
```

I think its because of the standard values which i have created. Can anyone help me in creating the standard values and assigning workflow to it.

Comment: helpful link - https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/01/how-to-manage-default-field-values-in-sitecore-cms/

Comment: Dont you need to assign the standard values item to standard values field of the template created?